# CakePHP: Uploading an Image directly to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Im a CakePHP beginner and I would like to know how to upload Image files directly to MySQL database using LONGBLOB field without uploading the image to the WWW_ROOT folder/directory. Is it possible to skip the move_uploaded_file thingy during the upload process? Thanks for the responses :)

Comment: Ive tried the move_uploaded_file thingy but im stuck at making the directory (mkdir permission denied error). So im thinking of uploading the image to a longblob.

Comment: wont even attempt to answer your question because imo storing images in a db is not a good idea. blob data types are ok, but it'll slow your db down if you get lots of images. just store url in db, and image on file system. this is the fastest way

Comment: You got file/directory permission errors and decided to go on a completely different direction instead of fixing that? Don't let problems define your strategy, this will always lead you on strange paths like what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for the responses, tried playing with the permissions and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the content of uploaded image file without storing in your filesystem using "move_uploaded_file()" with the help of code given below:

```
$uploadedImageFileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']);<br /><br />
```

And the uploaded image file content can be stored in database in a LONGBLOB field.